# Querying datastore with NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to use Python and NDB to access the datastore, which contains one entity:

[image]

I've defined by NDB model with the following code:

```
class Test(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    val = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

Then I run a query for the entity:

```
query = Test.get_by_id("Testing")
```

This returns a `NoneType` with no `val` field. I tried setting the argument to `name=Testing` instead of `Testing`, but that doesn't help.

What can I do to access my entity in Python? Do I need to identify the project's ID somewhere?

Also, I've been using Flask to serve as the microframework. But all the NDB example code I've seen uses webapp2. Should I use webapp2 instead?

Comment: In the UI, you're querying a model named `test`, in your code the model is `Test`.

Comment: Ha, that was it. Thank you! If you'll submit your response as an answer, I'll be sure to accept it.

Comment: webapp vs flask makes no difference by the way - you can use either with ndb in the standard 2.7 environment.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalization matters in Python. Instead of "Test", you need to query from the model "test".